# Multiple CASE with concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, case

I need to use a multiple CASE statements while concatenating 2 columns from a table.

Here is the scneario, how can we achieve this.

In my select we are concatenating col1 + col3 from Table A.

> From TABLE A,
>   when col2 value is NULL and
>    if COL3 value is 0000
>     then pick value from COL1 of TABLE B
>     ELSE if COL3 value IS NOT EQUAL TO 0000
>      pick value from COL2 of TABLE B

Table A:

```
col1 col2 col3
aa   null 0000
bb   null 1234
```

Table b:

```
col1 col2  col3
LMNO PQRST
```

I tried something like this which is not working,

```
select
 (a.col1 || '+' || a.col3) 
 CASE WHEN (a.col2 IS NULL) THEN
    CASE WHEN (a.col3 = '0000') THEN
     (Select col1 from b)
     ELSE (a.col3 <> '0000')
     (Select col2 from b)
 ELSE
  a.col2 
 as TEST
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output for various scenarios would be useful.

Comment: Query needs from A at the end

Comment: realation there is an another column which will have same value in both tabled

Comment: post the third table with relations please to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the join condition is based  on `a.column_will_have_same_value  = b.column_will_have_same_value`

```
select (a.col1 || '+' || a.col3) 
,  CASE WHEN a.col2 IS NULL AND a.col3 = '0000' THEN b.col1
        WHEN a.col2 IS NULL AND a.col3 <> '0000' THEN b.col2
        WHEN a.col2 IS NOT NULL A THEN a.col2
    END  as TEST
 FROM tableA a 
 inner join tableB b on a.column_will_have_same_value  = b.column_will_have_same_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are expecting?

```
proc sql;
select 
case
    when a.col2 is null and a.col3='0000' then a.col1||b.col1
    when a.col3<>'0000' then a.col1||b.col2
end as value

from tablea a, tableb b;
quit;
```